# Android SSO login dialog disappears immediately with no errors

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I set up SSO on my android application using the tutorial [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/authenticate/), but whenever I click on the login button, it attempts to open the facebook application, the facebook app says "loading", but fails immediately with no error message, and closes my app. Nothing of interest shows when i filter logcat out to show things related to facebook.

I copied the code exactly from the tutorial, and I am not sure why it closes immediately.  I tried to set an error listener on the LoginButton, but it never gets called.

According to [this blog post](http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/), the problem is supposedly with the key hash, but I had the key hash already in the facebook developer portal.  I even created a new keystore, hashed that, and tried it again.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Including the related code would improve the question.

Comment: Can you also make sure your Facebook for Android app is updated to the latest update?

Comment: Did you add the key hash to your overall developer settings or for the app itself? The former is for the sample apps, the latter for your own. The full walkthrough in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ covers both parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few days of hitting my head on my desk, I just restarted my whole app, starting from a facebook sample application, and rebuilding my app.  I realized that in my android manifest for the activity, i set `no:history="true"`.  Since Facebook SSO launches the Facebook app, and then goes back to my splash activity, it was simply exiting my application.

Thanks for the comments!

Comment: If Facebook official app is installed on your device then your android application is work or not?

Comment: It didn't work either way.  If the app was installed, it would launch the facebook app for a second, and then quit out of my application.  If it wasn't, the facebook web screen would launch, and then quit out of my application too.

Comment: Thanks!!! I had the same problem but after reading this I realized that I was launching the activity containing Facebook login with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY!